# Luxembourg citizen restricted from traveling abroad

Tags: luxembourg

This is purely theoretical question.

Is it possible for a Luxembourg citizen to be restricted from traveling abroad, i.e. the person cannot leave Luxembourg borders? (like it is the case for certain people in some countries, e.g. Russia)

Comment: The legal jurisdictions I am familiar with typically restrict the freedom of movement under some circumstances, such as when someone is awaiting trial.  I do not know specifically about the laws of Luxembourg.

Answer (score 2):

In general Luxembourg does not forbid anyone from leaving the country.

A court may impose restrictions on someone leaving, for example if they are accused of a crime. Excepting those with a legal right to reside in the country, there is no guarantee that a person will be admitted back after leaving.

Comment: Just to note that a citizen of a country *always* has the right to reside in that country, and Luxembourg is a signatory to the relevant international agreements (UDHR) that state this. Also, Luxembourg can revoke a citizen's passport, effectively ending their ability to cross into another country by a controlled border or board an airliner. There might be other ways to prevent someone from leaving as well....